# RecyclerView shows only two textview?others are not display...items are not displaying

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, android-recyclerview

i have facing issue like only two items are displayed others two items are not displayed they are contact and flat no this items are not displaying...i tried also removing and adding others textview but through this only two items are displayed.... Now I want to display the data on a RecyclerView which doesn't seem to work, I'm pretty sure that my code is good but something doesn't seem to work and I can't find it.i also try all the things suggested by stackoverflow but nothing can happen so that i think i need to ask...
Here the file

```
public class RecieptFP extends AppCompatActivity {
    private RecyclerView mFirestoreList;
    private FirebaseFirestore firebasefirestore;
    private FirestoreRecyclerAdapter adapter;
    Button Back;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_reciept_fp);
        Back = findViewById(R.id.btndashboard);

        firebasefirestore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
        mFirestoreList = findViewById(R.id.firestore_list);

        //query
        Query query = firebasefirestore.collection("UserDataR");
        //RecyclerOptions
        FirestoreRecyclerOptions<RecieptModel> options = new FirestoreRecyclerOptions.Builder<RecieptModel>()
                .setQuery(query, RecieptModel.class)
                .build();
        adapter = new FirestoreRecyclerAdapter<RecieptModel, RecieptViewHolder>(options) {
            @NonNull
            @Override
            public RecieptViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
                View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.listsingleiteam, parent, false);
                return new RecieptViewHolder(view);
            }

            @Override
            protected void onBindViewHolder(RecieptViewHolder recieptViewHolder, int i, RecieptModel recieptModel) {
                recieptViewHolder.list_name.setText(recieptModel.getName());
                recieptViewHolder.list_amount.setText(recieptModel.getAmount());
                recieptViewHolder.list_contact.setText(recieptModel.getContact());
                recieptViewHolder.list_Flatno.setText(recieptModel.getFlatNo());
            }
        };
        //viewholder
        mFirestoreList.setHasFixedSize(false);
        mFirestoreList.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        mFirestoreList.setAdapter(adapter);

        Back.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent i1 = new Intent(RecieptFP.this, Dashboard.class);
                startActivity(i1);

            }
        });
    }


    private class RecieptViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        private TextView list_name;
        private TextView list_amount;
        private TextView list_contact;
        private TextView list_Flatno;

        public RecieptViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            list_name = itemView.findViewById(R.id.list_name);
            list_amount = itemView.findViewById(R.id.list_amount);
            list_contact = itemView.findViewById(R.id.list_contact);
            list_Flatno = itemView.findViewById(R.id.list_Flatno);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        adapter.startListening();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        adapter.stopListening();
    }

}
```

Recipet Model

```
package com.societypay;

public class RecieptModel {
    private  String Name;
    private  String Amount;
    private String Contact;
    private String FlatNo;

    private  RecieptModel(){}
    private RecieptModel(String Name,String Amount,String Contact,String FlatNo){
        this.Name=Name;
        this.Amount=Amount;
        this.Contact=Contact;
        this.FlatNo=FlatNo;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return Name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        Name = name;
    }

    public String getAmount() {
        return Amount;
    }

    public void setAmount(String amount) {
        Amount = amount;
    }

    public String getContact() {
        return Contact;
    }

    public void setContact(String contact) {
        Contact = contact;
    }


    public String getFlatNo() {
        return FlatNo;
    }

    public void setFlatNo(String flatNo) {
        FlatNo = flatNo;
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Please post database structure

Comment: Please edit your question and add your database structure as a screenshot and the content of your `RecieptModel` class. Please respond with @AlexMamo

Comment: @AlexMamo Thanks for your reply i edit this post by screenshot please solve this

Comment: @Ashish i edit this post b y database structure

Comment: @DharmikShah Please also add the content of your `RecieptModel` class, as requested.

Comment: @AlexMamo i also added this recieptmodel

Comment: Your field names are not correct. Check the duplicate to see how you can fix this issue.

Comment: @AlexMamo Thanks for your help alex i solved this question...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please use following pojo and try.

```
public class RecieptModel
{
    private String MobileNo;

    private String Amount;

    private String Flat_no;

    private String Name;

    public String getMobileNo ()
    {
        return MobileNo;
    }

    public void setMobileNo (String MobileNo)
    {
        this.MobileNo = MobileNo;
    }

    public String getAmount ()
    {
        return Amount;
    }

    public void setAmount (String Amount)
    {
        this.Amount = Amount;
    }

    public String getFlat_no ()
    {
        return Flat_no;
    }

    public void setFlat_no (String Flat_no)
    {
        this.Flat_no = Flat_no;
    }

    public String getName ()
    {
        return Name;
    }

    public void setName (String Name)
    {
        this.Name = Name;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return "ClassPojo [MobileNo = "+MobileNo+", Amount = "+Amount+", Flat_no = "+Flat_no+", Name = "+Name+"]";
    }
}
```